# Howto move a file back down the directory tree on Github Web

Tags: github

Using only the web interface I moved a file into a new directory by renaming the file in the filename input field.

That was a mistake, now I need to move it back down a directory...

how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/blog/1436-moving-and-renaming-files-on-github

simply prefix the filename (in the input field) with `..`, the path prefixing the input field will reduce one directory.